# C# - Coordinates of splitted lines

Tags: c#, geometry

I want to split a canvas line into multiple parts of the same size `Ls`. But in C# I only have the coordinates for the line available. For point `A = {x1, y1}` and for point `B = {x2, y2}`.
Now I need the coordinates for each separated part of the line...

[image]

Comment: Sound like a job for y = m*x+c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a line of `A[x=0,y=0]` and `B[x=9,y=9]` you split into 3 sub-lines

- `A1[x=0,y=0]` and `B1[x=3,y=3]`
- `A2[x=3,y=3]` and `B2[x=6,y=6]`
- `A3[x=6,y=6]` and `B3[x=9,y=9]`

You have 2 classes: `line` which is made of 2 `point`s:

```
public class point
{
    public double x { get; set; }
    public double y { get; set; }
}

public class line
{
    public point p1 { get; set; }
    public point p2 { get; set; }

    public line(point p1, point p2)
    {
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
    }

    public List<line> SplitLine(int parts)
    {
        List<point> result = new List<point>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= parts; i++)
        {
            result.Add(new point()
            {
                x = this.p1.x + (i * (this.p2.x - this.p1.x) / parts),
                y = this.p1.y + (i * (this.p2.y - this.p1.y) / parts)
            });
        }
        return Enumerable.Range(0, parts).Select(x => new line(result[x], result[x + 1])).ToList();
    }
}
```

usage:

```
//creating the line with 2 points
line l = new line(
    new point() { x = 0, y = 0 },
    new point() { x = 9, y = 9 }
    );           

List<line> result = l.SplitLine(3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's there are N parts and coordinate differences are

```
Dx = B.X - A.X
Dy = B.Y - A.Y
```

Then coordinates of i-th segment end are

```
P[i].X = A.X + i * Dx / N
P[i].Y = A.Y + i * Dy / N
```